# I'm trying to call a function from deployed contract, i get the following error

Tags: remix

Gas estimation failed
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Invalid JSON RPC response:

[Contract source code](https://etherscan.io/address/0x55f359a60d458d3d215e7a51539084fc3f65daad#code)

trying to call `mint` function.

Comment: Could you transaction you are going to send and smart contract you are going to sent your transaction to?  Most probably your transaction is about to fail, that's why node cannot estimate its gas cost.

Comment: sorry, i'm not sure about what you mean. The contract has already been deployed, i want to call a function now. It's on the main net by the way

Comment: Could you post a link to contract's source code and tell what function are you trying to call and what are parameter values you are passing to it?

Comment: https://etherscan.io/address/0x55f359a60d458d3d215e7a51539084fc3f65daad#code

Comment: trying to call mint function. It takes an address and amount

Comment: It seems that `mint` functions can only be called from address 0x1acfb64c2ec4c3bad94e4667fe66e39e3617c4ad, are you trying to call it from this address of some other address?

Comment: trying to call from 0x1acfb64c2ec4c3bad94e4667fe66e39e3617c4ad

Comment: it should be pretty easy, not sure why it isn't the case

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call `mint` function on [Allocation](https://etherscan.io/address/0x55f359a60d458d3d215e7a51539084fc3f65daad#code) smart contract, but it does not have such function.  That's why your transaction is going to fail.

You probably need to call `mint` on [OPUCoin](https://etherscan.io/address/0xedf66033e74cd7734316c4cb5aeaa2e8f7f620c8#code) smart contract.  This function may only be called by smart contract owner, and the owner of `OPUCoin` smart contract is `Allocation` smart contract, so you need to somehow make `Allocation` smart contract to call `mint` on `OPUCoin`.  There are several method in `Allocation` smart contract that are able to call `mint` on `OPUToken`, e.g. `allocate`, `allocateIntoHolding`, `finalizeHoldingAndTeamTokens`, `optAddressIntoHolding`.  You may try calling some of these methods.

**Explanation**

You have two smart contracts deployed: [Allocation](https://etherscan.io/address/0x55f359a60d458d3d215e7a51539084fc3f65daad#code) and [OPUCoin](https://etherscan.io/address/0xedf66033e74cd7734316c4cb5aeaa2e8f7f620c8#code) and these smart contracts are mutually relative in many ways:

1. `OPUCoin` smart contract was deployed by `Allocation` smart contract.
2. Property `token` of `Allocation` smart contract holds a reference to `OPUCoin` smart contract.
3. Property `owner` of `OPUCoint` smart contract holds a reference to `Allocation` smart contract.
4. Many function `Allocation` smart contract call functions of `OPUCoin` smart contract.

Comment: Can you please provide the specifics? I want to mint some coins, should I call "allocate"? thanks

Comment: You may try calling `allocate` from address `0x54650daf32afbfe0fff592f249e0652e539749dc` (the only address authorized to call `allocate`), but there is quite complicated logic inside and I'm not sure it will allow you to `mint` any tokens.

Comment: tried calling 'allocate', transaction failed and got the following: JsonRpcEngine - response has no error or result for request:
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1243108505,
  "method": "eth_estimateGas",
  "params": [
    {
      "from": "0x1acfb64c2ec4c3bad94e4667fe66e39e3617c4ad",
      "to": "0x55f359A60D458D3D215E7A51539084FC3F65DaAD",
      "data": "0x79ba5097",
      "value": "0x0"
    }
  ]
} 
transact to OPUCoin.mint pending ... 

[block:7451130 txIndex:1]from:0x1ac...7c4adto:0x55f...5daadvalue:0 wei

Comment: you're saying there's no way to mint tokens with this contract now?

Comment: I didn't say this.  I sad that in order to mint tokens you have to convince `Allocation` contract to call `mint` on `OPUCoin` contract.  Whether it is possible or not depends on `Allocation` smart contract logic.

Comment: The logic is quite complicated and its behavior depends on many factors such as: who calls it, what function is called, what parameters are passed to this function, what is current time, what is smart contract state etc.  If you will find combination of these factors that leads to `mint` called on `OPUCoin` then you will have tokens minted for you.

Comment: the token address of `allocate` turns out to be https://etherscan.io/address/0xEDf66033e74Cd7734316C4CB5AEaa2e8f7f620c8#code. Not sure how it's linked to https://etherscan.io/address/0x55f359a60d458d3d215e7a51539084fc3f65daad#code

Comment: what if i write a seperate Allocation and cold storage contract and deploy them seperately and then call the functions from there?

Comment: Added some explanation to the answer.  About your latest comment, I don't known whether what you suggested will help or not.  This depends on what new `Allocation` contract you will write and what you are trying to achieve.